# Crop in cjuidialog

Tags: yii, image, crop, cjuidialog

I need to do an upload with crop picture but I can not find information to operate the extension eajaxupload, coconut inside cjuidialog

any extension for yii?

something like:

http://uvumitools.com/crop.html

http://kroppr.rborn.info/index.php

Answer (score 0):

yes sure there is a yii extension, you can use http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image which is a wrapper of the Kohana Image Module.The available image manipulation methods are resize, crop, sharpen, quality and rotate or flip.

However you can also find standalone php libraries like http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/ which works well with yii